# XSLT2 - test which node comes first among options

Tags: xml, xslt

Given this structure:

```
<body>
  <h1>Main Title</h1>
  <p class="sectiontitle>Title</p>
  <p class="bodytext">some text</bodytext>
  <ul>...</ul>
  <p class="paragraphtitle>Subtitle</p>
  <p class="bodytext">some text</bodytext>
</body>
```

or this one where the paragraphtitle and sectiontitle are reversed:

```
<h1>Main Title</h1>
  <p class="paragraphtitle>Title</p>
  <p class="bodytext">some text</bodytext>
  <ul>...</ul>
  <p class="sectiontitle>Subtitle</p>
  <p class="bodytext">some text</bodytext>
</body>
```

I am transforming this XML structure into a different flavor of XML (DITA) and for this, I need to know what node comes first because that tells me how to process the rest of the file.
There is no other way for me to process the file until I know what came first.
I know there will be a h1, h2, h3... element before any of these titles. There might be `<p class=bodytext>` elements anywhere between the main title and the closing body tag. It is very random.

How can I tell what comes first: the sectiontitle p or the paragraphtitle p.

I've tried with some crazy expressions put in a choose like:

```
body/p[@class='sectiontitle'][1]/preceding-sibling::p[@class!='paragraphtitle'][last()]/preceding-sibling::*[not(self::p[@class='sectiontitle' or @class='paragraphtitle']) and preceding-sibling::h1]
```

or

```
body/p[@class='paragraphtitle'][1]/preceding-sibling::p[@class!='sectiontitle'][last()]/preceding-sibling::*[not(self::p[@class='sectiontitle' or @class='paragraphtitle']) and preceding-sibling::h1]
```

That works in most cases (still need to tweak something), but I feel there must be something simpler to tell what node comes first in a list of possibilities.

Is there a way to get an absolute position? Something like

```
if absposition(paragraphtitle[1]) < absposition(sectiontitle[1]) then
```

Comment: Why do you need to know which comes first? What is the **real** problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: I am trying to identify the file to know how to process it, I know of 2 shapes: sectiontitle first, of paragraphtitle first, based on that, I take a different path for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to get an absolute position? Something like if
>   `absposition(paragraphtitle[1]) < absposition(sectiontitle[1]) then`

I believe your condition could be restated  as:

> If there is a `paragraphtitle` before the first `sectiontitle`, then…

which could be expressed as:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="/body/p[@class='sectiontitle'][1]/preceding-sibling::p[@class='paragraphtitle']">paragraph title is first</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>section title is first</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

---

This would work for both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0. As already mentioned, in XSLT 2.0 you could model the test to fit exactly your original statement:

```
<xsl:when test="/body/p[@class='paragraphtitle'][1] &lt;&lt; /body/p[@class='sectiontitle'][1]">paragraph title is first</xsl:when>
```

or:

```
<xsl:when test="/body/p[@class='sectiontitle'][1] >> /body/p[@class='paragraphtitle'][1]">paragraph title is first</xsl:when>
```

Comment: That's much simpler than I expected and that does the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0 you can use the `<<` operator:

```
if (p[@class='paragraphtitle'] << p[@class='sectiontitle']) ...
```

In 1.0 you've got no real option other than preceding-sibling and following-sibling. But I can't really advise on the detail because your candidate expressions in include detail that isn't needed to distinguish these two samples (e.g. testing for the `h1` element which is present in both), and I assume you put those extra conditions in there for a reason.

Another option (needs the node-set extension) is to filter the list by excluding all the elements that aren't interesting, and then test the filtered list using `<xsl:if test="p[1][self::sectiontitle]">`.

Or perhaps one should ask why you are doing this, what is the real underlying problem? Perhaps your real aim is to reorder the elements into some canonical order, in which case we should be looking at sorting techniques.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Michael. I have added a bit of information, but I'm facing files that vary a lot. i just found the node-before function trying to find info on the << operator you mentioned. I'm going to give it a go.

Comment: Note that you cannot use the `<<` operator without escaping it as `&lt;&lt;`.

Comment: @Flag the op:node-before function is just there as a way of specifying the semantics of the `<<` operator. The function isn't available as such to user applications.

Comment: Indeed, thank you the explanation. I ended up using a different way though, but hopefully this will help others! Thank you!